# Electric field a distance $z$ above the center of a circular loop. The Hard way

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electric-fields, vectors

> *Problem 2.5: Find the electric field a distance $z$ above the center of a circular loop of radius $r$ which carries a uniform line charge $\lambda$.*

This problem is in refereced here (with solution): http://teacher.pas.rochester.edu/PHY217/LectureNotes/Chapter2/LectureNotesChapter2.html

But it is solved using a trick. The trick is: okay we know there is symmetry so let us just take the magnitude and not use the vectors. The problem I have is I am unable to solve it without using the trick and I would appreciate someones help in doing the problem without the shortcut, using the vectors. When I do it the r compontent doesn't cancel.

Using polar coordinates here is the setup:

$$dE = \frac{1}{4 \pi \epsilon_0} \frac{\lambda}{\rho^2} ~ \hat{\rho} ~ r d \theta$$

$$\hat{\rho} = \frac{z \hat{k} + r \hat{r}}{\sqrt{z^2 + r^2}} $$

$$ E = \frac{\lambda}{4 \pi \epsilon_0} \int_0^{2 \pi} \frac{r z \hat{z} + r^2 \hat{r} }{(z^2 + r^2)^{3/2}} ~ d \theta$$

$$ E = \frac{\lambda}{4 \pi \epsilon_0} \int_0^{2 \pi} \frac{r z \hat{z} }{(z^2 + r^2)^{3/2}} ~ d \theta + \frac{\lambda}{4 \pi \epsilon_0} \int_0^{2 \pi} \frac{r^2 \hat{r} }{(z^2 + r^2)^{3/2}} ~ d \theta $$

If I now evaluate the $z$ component I get the correct answer. When I evaluate the $r$ component, shown below the $r$ doesn't not cancel the way it should. why not?

$$\frac{\lambda}{4 \pi \epsilon_0} \frac{r^2 2 \pi }{(z^2 + r^2)^{3/2}} -  \frac{\lambda}{4 \pi \epsilon_0} \frac{r^2 0 }{(z^2 + r^2)^{3/2}} $$

$$ = \frac{\lambda}{4 \pi \epsilon_0} \frac{r^2 2 \pi }{(z^2 + r^2)^{3/2}} \hat{r}$$

Comment: note that $\hat{r}$ is not a constant vector!

Comment: Duplicate : http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/62637/the-potential-and-the-intensity-of-the-gravitational-field-in-the-axis-of-a-circ/62919#62919

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recall that $\hat r$ *depends on $\theta$* in the following way:
$$
  \hat r = \cos\theta \,\hat x +\sin\theta \,\hat y
$$
It follows that
$$
  \int_0^ {2\pi }\hat r \,d\theta = \hat x \int_0^ {2\pi}\cos\theta \, d\theta + \hat y \int_0^{2\pi}\sin\theta \,d\theta = 0+0
$$